# editing resource of another C# application

Tags: c#, resources, assemblies

I have two complied C# assemblies, however I'm wanting one to be able to add string resources to the second one while the second exe is **not** running. Sorry this question is so brief but I'm not too sure where to even start here.

**Edit:** Sorry, just to add - both of these compiled assemblied will be on the clients computer, so doing this through Visual Studio or anything outside of the .NET framework is a bit of a no no.

Comment: This sounds bizarre. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Editing resources in existing .net assemblies.](http://fortheloveofcode.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/change-resources-inside-assembly/)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the comment - although from what I can understand of that page, it relies on ildasm which is something that only comes packaged with the SDK rather than the runtime .NET framework.

Comment: @R4D4 - hmm... editing assembly resources is pretty much hacking into the assembly. Do you expect to be able to hack assembly without installing extra software? :)

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough - I still haven't got to grips with C# assemblies yet at all. I (very wrongly) assumed that because it is quite simple with the WinAPI targeting normal PE exes that C# should be just as simple. Thank you anyway. :)